# Let $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6},$ then which of the following is/are true?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

For any natural number $n,\;$ Let $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \dfrac{1}{r^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6},$$ Then which of the following is/are true?

(A) $$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(
1+x)}{x}dx=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$$

(B) $$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(
1-x)}{x}dx=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

(C) $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^k \ln x \;dx=1-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

(D) $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x} dx=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$$

**My Doubt:** In solution for option (A)

It is given that $\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(
1+x)}{x}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n} dn=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$

And for option (B)

$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(
1-x)}{x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2} dn=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$

And for option (C)

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^k \ln x \;dx=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}$.

I don't know how did they convert given integral form into these kind of form in solution. I only know that we put $\dfrac{r}{n}=x$ and $\dfrac{1}{n}=dx$ when we convert sum into integral.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are writing $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ for expressions that do not depend on $n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I've edited the question

Comment: Use log Taylor series expansion

Comment: First integral should be with dx not dn

Comment: @sku Even If i am using expansion of $\log (1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\cdots .$ I am not obtaining the result.

Comment: Surely from the properties of logs one would have D = A+B ?

Comment: For C, perhaps $y=1-x$ and ${1 \over 1-y} = 1+y+y^2+\cdots$. Would need to subtract off $\int_0^1 \log$

Comment: integrate log(1+x) and use the alternating sign of sum(1/n^2) is half of $\pi^2/6$

Comment: Would people ever stop [abusing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) `\dfrac`?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx = \int_{0}^{1} \left(1-\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{3}+\cdots\right)dx = 1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2} - \cdots = \frac{\pi^2}{12},$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx= -\int_{0}^{1} \left(1+\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{3}+\cdots\right)dx = -1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}-\dfrac{1}{3^2} -\cdots = -\frac{\pi^2}{6},$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^k \ln x dx = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(x^{k+1}\log(x)/(k+1)\vert_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{x^k}{k+1} dx\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{(k+1)^2} = 1 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

As someone said $D = A + B = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}$. Note the answer for D given by OP is $+\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ which is incorrect.

Comment: "The answer for D is incorrect".  That is why the question asks "which of the following is/are true?".

Answer (score 1):

A,B,C are correct! But NOT D, Because $ln(1-x^{2})=ln(1-x)+ln(1+x)$ which implies that the value of the integral is $\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$ Also in your comments you say that the integral A is a negative number namely $-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$ whereas it is positive and equal to $\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$.The sentence "It is given etc" is incorrect. Please make the necessary corrections!

Comment: It's not usually necessary to correct questions, especially since answers might explain/discuss the original error in a helpful way.